# WPF 4, ListView and ListCollectionView custom sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

I'm trying to use a custom sort with a ListView, as described [in this blog entry.](http://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/a-much-faster-sorting-for-listview-in-wpf/)

I'm doing

```
ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TheList.ItemsSource);
```

as recommended there and in several other places, but for some reason I'm getting "Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView' to type 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView'." (TheList is of type ListView).

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the underlying type of the source collection - i.e. `TheList.ItemsSource` is not a `List` but perhaps `IEnumerable`. Here is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/03/14/wpf-discussion-090313.aspx) with more info.

Quick solution - use `List<Whatever>` as `ItemsSource` for `TheList`.

Comment: I was using the result of a Linq query - a .ToList() fixed it immediately. I had no idea the underlying type of the ItemsSource mattered. Thanks!